# Laravel 10 / Inertia Authentication does not work on production

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I created an application with Laravel 10 and Inertia.
On the local server everything works fine. I have not had any problems.
In production, on the other hand, several problems have arisen. The latest is authentication. It basically does not create the session. The write permissions have been set on the server **framework/session**. I have also tried creating other types of sessions, but it does not work. I cannot understand why.

**Here the code used**

```
if (!Auth::attempt($request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]), true)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => 'Authentication failed'
        ]);
    }

    $request->session()->regenerate();



    return redirect()->route('home');
```

The code works locally but not on the server.

Comment: It's probably related to your Sanctum settings and not your login code.

Comment: I am not using api for authentication.